# Multiply a 5 x 16 Column Dataframe by a 5 x 1 Column Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

df1

```
  C1 C2 C3
1  1  1  1
2  5  5  5
3  8  8  8
4  9  9  9
```

df 2

```
   D1
1 2.0
2 1.0
3 2.0
4 0.5
```

I want to multiply df1 by df2 such that each column is df1 is multiplied by df 2 to produce a new dataframe with the results and same column names of df1

I keep getting TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your values in dataframe `df1` are of type string. Convert it to integers before multiply:

```py
x = df1.astype(int).mul(df2.values, axis=1)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
     C1    C2    C3
1   2.0   2.0   2.0
2   5.0   5.0   5.0
3  16.0  16.0  16.0
4   4.5   4.5   4.5
```